# Where in the CSS code to edit post margins on Wisteria template?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am brand new to website design. I found the code to delete the sidebar on my single post page - now there is a large white space on the right side where the sidebar was. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A simple google found [this link](https://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/editing-css/).  Please refer to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)  and read all of the posts under the "Asking" section to learn more about posting proper questions here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

if the sidebar is inside a div, then i think you should use

```
.sidediv
{
    display:none;
}
```

this will remove the side div and that space will be occupied by other div

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want

```
#idLeftDiv{
width:100%;
display:block;
}
#idRightDiv{
display:none
}
```